# post-decrement of NF in awk

Tags: awk

I'm a bit confused by the following:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF--; print NF}'
3:2
$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; $NF=""; NF -= 1; print NF}' 
3:2
$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; $(NF--)=""; print NF}' 
3:3
```

I see the same behavior in `awk version 20070501` (macos) and `GNU Awk 4.0.2`.  Why does the post-decrement of NF in the 3rd case not apply?  Is that behavior expected, mandated by a standard, or a quirk of the implementation?

---

EDIT by Ed Morton: FWIW I'd find the following a more compelling example:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; NF--; $NF=""; print NF}'
3:2

$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; --NF; $NF=""; print NF}'
3:2

$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; $NF=""; NF--; print NF}'
3:2

$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; $NF=""; --NF; print NF}'
3:2

$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; $(--NF)=""; print NF}'
3:2

$ echo foo bar baz | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; $(NF--)=""; print NF}'
3:3
```

with the question being why does the last example (post-decrement with assignment) behave differently from all of the other cases, regardless of which one you think it should be equivalent to.

Comment: e.g. `echo 'foo bar baz' | awk '{printf "%d:", NF; $(--NF)=""; print NF}'` will output `3:2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of a post-decrement is the value of the variable before it's decremented. Because of this, the last case is adding a new field after it decrements `NF`, which updates `NF`.

```
$(NF--) = "";
```

is equivalent to

```
temp = NF;  # temp == 3
NF--;       # NF == 2
$temp = ""; # adds a new field 3, so now NF == 3
```

Comment: True, but given that it works in this implementation, this is what it's doing.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's what's happening all right. We could test it of course by using a post-increment for similar functionality - that behavior IS specified by POSIX so it'd remove "undefined behavior" from the equation. @AndyLester I removed that comment as I don't think it actually is relevant to this after all, I was too quick to dismiss it as "just don't do that" (though I do still think that's the best advice!).